# Rewrite outbound links with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Is there a way to rewrite the URL's for outbound links on my website? I expect .htaccess would be the only answer. It is not possible to change the links manually.

I need to redirect all links to `http://www.example.com` to `http://www.anothersite.com` or even to a custom error file. The aim is to block outbound links to one single domain whether it is by redirection or simply serving them an error page.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Nope, mod_rewrite works once a request has reached _your_ server – which a request to `http://www.google.com/` (assuming that’s one of your outbound links you _don’t_ want) will never do.

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997002/how-to-redirect-any-external-links-to-a-specific-url-format-using-htaccess

Comment: @Simone, that shows for people visiting my website, not for users leaving the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As correctly written by [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) as a comment [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772242/rewrite-outbound-links-with-htaccess#comment29386925_19772242):

> Nope, mod_rewrite works once a request has reached your server – which a request to http://www.google.com/ (assuming that’s one of your outbound links you don’t want) will never do.

To elaborate further, .htaccess only applies when people are visiting the website. This does not apply to outbound links and thus will not be able to have any effect.

The only way this could be done is through modifying the html output on the server side before it is given to the user, for example, you could remove all unwanted links on any text retrieved from a database prior to serving it to the user.

Comment: I've written this as a community wiki answer as the answer was not discovered by me but instead through the help of numerous comments above, so I don't deserve to take the credit for the answer. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

> `The aim is to block outbound links to one single domain whether it is by redirection or simply serving them an error page.`

Redirection is indeed possible. put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.anothersite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Will that work for links leaving my website? It looks like it would simply redirect people who are attempting to access my site from that domain, I may be mistaken though.

Comment: As I wrote it will be a redirect. mod_rewrite cannot change content of your webpage but when visitors click on `http://example.com/abc`, they will be permanently redirected to `http://anothersite.com/abc` Since 301 is being used bowsers will also aggressively cache this.

Comment: I will test this and see what happens.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I'm not really sure what it's doing - but it's not doing what I wanted. Thanks regardless

Comment: So, the workflow is: link produced to _this_ site _on_ this site, visitor clicks on it, _incoming_ link is redirected to another site? So, for example it could **not** be used to change a dynamic link _to_ SEO format on the fly, so that the visitor sees only the SEO format link and not the ugly dynamic form? I think that's sort of what the OP was asking for (a different domain rather than a different format, but still a modified outgoing link).

Comment: this isn't working for me either. I really just want to redirect traffic that is being linked away from my site to a specific other site, back to my site.

Comment: You need to understand that your web server won't be called when someone clucks on an outbound link on a web page. These rules cannot change your page's HTML source.