# How to redirect ANY external links to a specific url format using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all the external links, i.e., links like `http://www.someothersite.com/anything` in my site(say `http://www.example.com`) to `http://www.example.com/something`.

Here the problem I am facing is how to take care of `http://www.someothersite.com/anything` because its value is not fixed. It could be from any different domain.

Comment: Actual I think the goal is to try and prevent an external link from ever leaving the site in the first place, which can't be done to my knowledge... At least not via .htaccess.

Comment: Actually I have links to those sites in my website. Now what I want is when a user clicks on that external site's link, I want the person to be redirected to `http://www.example.com/something` (fixed)

Comment: That is what I want @WheatBeak

Comment: You can probably accomplish it via javascript, but not .htaccess.  An external link is going to work regardless of server-side settings. NOTE: doing this in javascript would probably have a drastic effect on site performance, especially if you have a lot of links.

Comment: @RyanVincent OP means if their site has a link to your domain, and a user clicks, they don't want to user to follow the link at all and instead redirect.

Comment: If you want to replace the external link `http://www.someothersite.com/anything` with the local link `http://www.thissite.com/anything` in your code, for example, maybe an editor to find and replace the strings will do it. Htaccess wont. Outgoing URIs are never processed by htaccess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `.htaccess` configures an HTTP Server which handles *incoming* requests, requests for resources on *your* server, not external ones. But since you've explicitely asked for a `.htaccess` way of redirecting external links, I will outline three approaches:

1. Use `.htaccess` and `mod_substitute` to replace all external links on your pages with a fixed internal one.
2. Use PHP and output buffering to replace all external links with internal ones.
3. Use JavaScript to redirect external links to internal ones on click.

All methods have advantages and disadvantages.

## 1. `.htaccess` and `mod_substitute`

If have not tested this, but theoretically, it should work.

Place the following in your `.htaccess` and replace `www.yourdomain.com` with your domain:

```
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute "s|(<a\s[^>]*)href=\"https?://([^/]+)(?<!www\.yourdomain\.com)/[^\"]*\"|$1href=\"http://www.yourdomain.com/your-fixed-link\"|i"
```

This adds an output filter to all request bodies with HTML content and uses a regular expression to replace any external URL in the `href` attribute of every link with your fixed one.

**Drawbacks:**

- Your domain must be fixed (`sub2.yourdomain.com` and `yourdomain.com` will be considered external).
- You must use an Apache HTTP server which has `mod_substitute` loaded.

## 2. PHP and output buffering

If you already use PHP to generate your pages, you can add output buffering with a callback which replaces external links with internal ones:

```
<?php
function replace_links($html)
{
    return preg_replace('~(<a\s[^>]*)href="https?://([^/]+)(?<!www\\.yourdomain\\.com)/[^"]*"~i', '$1href="http://www.yourdomain.com/your-fixed-link"', $html);
}

ob_start('replace_links');

// generate page
?>
```

This will prevent PHP from sending the content of the page directly to the browser, but writes everything to an internal buffer. At the end of the script, the callback is executed and may modify the content of that buffer before it will be sent to the browser.

**Advantages over the `.htaccess` method:** More control over the substitution. You could exclude more than one internal domain from the replacement by using `preg_replace_callback` in combination with a callback which checks the actual domain in the link. Furthermore, the substituted URL does not have to be fixed.

## 3. Redirecting with JavaScript

The following JavaScript probably is the most popular way of doing what you want:

```
(function() {
    function redirectLink(evt) {
        var matches = /^https?:\/\/([^\/]+)\//i.exec(this.href);
        if (matches && matches[1] != 'www.yourdomain.com') {
            window.location.href = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/your-fixed-link';
            evt.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }

    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'), i;
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
        links[i].addEventListener('click', redirectLink, false);
})();
```

Just make sure that this code is placed after all links (e.g. at the end of the document) or is executed on the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

**Advantages over the `.htaccess` method:** Same as with the PHP method described above.

**Disadvantages:** The user must have JavaScript enabled, so this is not guaranteed to work always.